# Combining 2 plots into 1 plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pie-chart

I want to plot 2 plots on one plot. Below is the code for the creating the plots. The plots are created, but I'm trying to put them together on the same plot. I don't think these plots are [plots] or [ggplots] types. Thanks.

```
library("fPortfolio")
library('fPortfolio')
data = SPISECTOR.RET
asset = dim(data)[2]

constraints <- c('minW[1:asset]=0','maxW[1:asset]=0.3')
spec <- portfolioSpec()
setNFrontierPoints(spec) <- 25
setSolver(spec)<- "solveRquadprog"

frontier <-portfolioFrontier(data, spec, constraints)

Pont <- 6

#I don't know if GGplot is needed
library(ggplot2)

#plot First Point [I don't think this is a ggplot]
plot1 <- weightsPie(object = frontier, pos = Pont, labels = F, col = rainbow(asset),
                    box = F, legend = F, radius = 0.8)

#plot Second Point [I don't think this is a ggplot]
plot2 <- weightsPie(object = frontier, pos = Pont, labels = T, col = rainbow(asset),
                    box = TRUE, legend = T, radius = 0)

#I want to Put the two plots on the same plot
library("gridExtra")
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, nrow=1, ncol=2)
```

Comment: What does `class(plot1)` return?  If it doesn't include `ggplot`, you're right - they're not ggplots, and `grid.arrange` won't work

Comment: it comes up as `numeric`. All I want to do is put the two plots into 1 plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is with `base R`, but it shows some output at least.
I used `layout` to arrange the plots:

```
# your previous code

layout(matrix(c(1, 2), nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE))
layout.show(n=2)

plot1 <- weightsPie(object = frontier, pos = Pont, labels = F, col = rainbow(asset),
                    box = F, legend = F, radius = 0.8)

plot2 <- weightsPie(object = frontier, pos = Pont, labels = T, col = rainbow(asset),
                    box = TRUE, legend = T, radius = 0)
```

Here the output:

["Arrangement"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBeVJ.png)

Comment: Thanks, I rearranged `nrow` to `ncol` and it works great. Can I save it as a plot in R (with ggplot)?

Comment: You can save it by hand: Export -> ... or might do something like this:  `pdf("arrangement", onefile = FALSE)` then place your layout and plot commands, and then end with `dev.off()`. Your plot will be stored to your working directory. You can change pdf to something else, e. g. png if you like.